# How to use the dart sort method (with sample code)

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart

The repository is below

https://github.com/kanari3/flutter_sort_sample

I sorted the items by startedDate, then tried to sort by startedDatetime within the startedDate range.

```
class Item {
  //required
  int id;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime startedDate;
  DateTime endedDate;
  //optional
  DateTime startedDatetime;
  DateTime endedDatetime;
```

While writing the if expression, I noticed that the return 0 was out of order.

[How to use the dart sort method (with sample code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64970800/how-to-use-the-dart-sort-method-with-sample-code)

The first sort result

```
result
id,  startedDate,              startedDateTime,          endedDatetime
2,   2020-11-06 00:00:00.000,  null                   ,  null
1,   2020-11-06 00:00:00.000,  2020-11-06 08:00:00.000,  2020-11-06 17:00:00.000
3,   2020-11-06 00:00:00.000,  null                   ,  null
4,   2020-11-07 00:00:00.000,  2020-11-07 08:00:00.000,  2020-11-07 17:00:00.000
5,   2020-11-07 00:00:00.000,  null                   ,  null
6,   2020-11-07 00:00:00.000,  null                   ,  null
7,   2020-11-08 00:00:00.000,  2020-11-08 08:00:00.000,  2020-11-08 17:00:00.000
```

Here, the startedDate is correctly sorted, although still not an ideal result.

My understanding.
I think the sort method swaps item1 and item2 if it is greater than or equal to 1, and does nothing if it is less than 0.

But the result is the following (second sort result)

```
result
id,  startedDate,              startedDateTime,          endedDatetime
12,  2020-11-12 00:00:00.000,  null                   ,  null
1,   2020-11-06 00:00:00.000,  2020-11-06 08:00:00.000,  2020-11-06 17:00:00.000
3,   2020-11-06 00:00:00.000,  null                   ,  null
.
.
```

Why is it?
Also, how do I solve the problem?

Testing is as follows

https://github.com/kanari3/flutter_sort_sample/blob/master/test/sort_test.dart

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a two-level comparison: compare startedDate first, and return the difference **if non-zero** only, otherwise (i.e., if startedDate-s are equal) compare startedDateTime. And the whole sorting will be done within a single call.

BTW, check the `sort()` documentation, possibly it does not guarantee the 'equal' items preserve their relative order...

Comment: I have reviewed the following documents

https://api.dart.dev/be/137051/dart-core/List/sort.html

>> And the whole sorting will be done within a single call <<

Does it mean that calling sort after sort would be out of order?

Comment: Have you reviewed it? So you should've seen this part: _A Comparator may compare objects as equal (return zero), even if they are distinct objects. The sort function is **not guaranteed to be stable**, so distinct objects that compare as equal **may occur in any order** in the result._ That's exactly what you get: objects with equal startedDateTime are grouped together by that value, but their order determined previously by startedDate is not preserved. Same applies to sorting with a comaparator `return 0;` – it says all items are equal, neverthless they do not keep the previous order.

Comment: Thank you. I finally understand the meaning of the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it's hard to write grouped sorting logic in one process.

Answer (score -1):

I found a good library!

https://pub.dev/packages/sorted

I solved the problem as follows.

https://github.com/kanari3/flutter_sort_sample/blob/master/lib/main.dart#L32-L44

```
items.sorted([
  SortedComparable<Item, DateTime>(
    (item) => item.startedDate,
  ),
  SortedComparable<Item, DateTime>(
    (item) => item.startedDatetime, invert: true,
  ),
  SortedComparable<Item, DateTime>(
    (item) => item.endedDatetime,
  ),
]);
```

That's amazing!